# How can I call a protected variable in a subclass method in an equals function?

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, instance-variables, protected

It is a pretty simple equals method.

Here's what I have in my code:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) 
      if (other == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!(other instanceof BinaryTree)) {
                return false;
            }
            return this.equalsUtil(this.root, other.root);
        }
```

Here's the initial problem

```
public class BinaryTree {
    protected class Node {
        //instancee variables and a constructor
    }
    protected Node root;
    //remainder ommited for brevity
```

I can't call `other.root` (`Object other` being the parameter for equals), how can I do this then?

Note that my class is `public class MyBinaryTree extends Bina`

Comment: `return this.equalsUtil(this.root, ((BinaryTree) other).root);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable being protected has nothing to do with this.  You just have to cast `other` to `BinaryTree`, e.g. `BinaryTree o = (BinaryTree) other; return this.equalsUtil(this.root, o.root);`

Answer (score 0):

Follow Elliots advice or create a get function to locate the exact value you want. Maybe make a function that checks if a node is root.  You need to check if the pointer to your node points to the same thing as root.

Comment: Thank you, I just forgot to mention we can't make / use getters here. Thank you though